# What is the best way to show data of table in database

Tags: tables

I have a table in my database with 200 columns in it, and the table can have maximum of 10 records in that.

Here search based on data is a least priority but search on the column name is the most used feature.

Sort feature is also required on the column names but not on data.

Comment: Could you have the records  as columns for the exhibition? in this case you would have a table with 10 columns and 200 rows. I think it would be easier to read and filter.

Comment: We need more information to understand how & why users need access to the information, the question is to light on information as it stands.

Comment: @Aline, going with your suggestion user need to go on pagination or lazy loading to get the rest of the data loaded, to read a single record data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special kind of databases called [Column oriented DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS). Maybe they have some useful UI patterns.

What we had in our case was a usual HTML table with most popular columns being visible. First column was locked and contained some unique key for rows, other columns were horizontally scrollable. First column of the header row contained [hamburger icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button), which in our case meant Column Control Menu. On pressing it, the huge popup menu appeared with alphabetical list of all possible columns. You could check/uncheck the columns you need. There was also a quick search for columns there.

For column oriented table you usually don't need to see all the columns at once, because data there is either sparse or not very unique.